# Why [NSDecimalNumber longLongValue] return min value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber

```
NSDecimalNumber *dn = [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"9223372036854775806"] autorelease];
long long llVal = [dn longLongValue];
```

why `llVal` is -9223372036854775808   ?

NSDecimalNumber extends NSNumber so it supposes to handle long long type. doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are running into a small base10->base2 rounding error in `-longLong`. I would open a defect at bugreport.apple.com. You should be able to round-trip a number within the long long range.

If you stay entirely in `NSDecimalNumber`, you will note that it does not suffer the rounding error. Here is some code that I think shows the problem very clearly:

```
unsigned long long longlong = 9223372036854775806;
NSLog(@"longlong: %lu", longlong);
NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:longlong exponent:0 isNegative:NO];
NSLog(@"dn-dn: %@", dn);    // Round-trips fine
NSLog(@"dn+10: %@", [dn decimalNumberByAdding:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]]);    // Even does math
NSLog(@"dn-lu: %lu", [dn unsignedLongValue]); // has rounding error

2011-03-07 23:56:15.132 Untitled[16059:a0f] longlong: 9223372036854775806
2011-03-07 23:56:15.135 Untitled[16059:a0f] dn-dn: 9223372036854775806
2011-03-07 23:56:15.135 Untitled[16059:a0f] dn+10: 9223372036854775816
2011-03-07 23:56:15.136 Untitled[16059:a0f] dn-lu: 9223372036854775808
```

Comment: I avoid this problem by [NSDecimalNumber stringValue] and call strtoll(). 
BTW, thanks to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

I think its because `longLongValue` method can be used at `NSString` and `NSNumber` and not on `NSDecimalNumber`.

I dont know it for sure but i think thats the reason the value of your variable is always             `-9223372036854775808` even if you change the string on `dn`

Comment: NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber. It should respond to any NSNumber selectors it doesn't explicitly disown.

Comment: I dont know but i tried to changing the value of dn to something else but still the same result.